# Calculation from 2 SQL queries

Tags: sql

I have two queries that I am not sure how to run as one doing some simple math.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMERINFO
where member between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
```

Returns:  7823

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT ORDERINFO.OrderID) from orderinfo, orderiteminfo 
where code = '810samp' 
AND ORDERINFO.OrderID = ORDERITEMINFO.OrderID
AND orderinfo.PrepareDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
```

Returns:  4106

I need to have the query return:  4106 / 7823 X 100

Comment: Is it MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this syntax:

```
SELECT (
  CAST((<your first query>) as decimal)
  /(<your second query>)
  * 100
  ) AS Percents;
```

So your query should be

```
SELECT (
  CAST((select COUNT(DISTINCT ORDERINFO.OrderID) from orderinfo, orderiteminfo 
        where code = '810samp' 
        AND ORDERINFO.OrderID = ORDERITEMINFO.OrderID
        AND orderinfo.PrepareDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31') as decimal)
  /(SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMERINFO
    where member between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
  * 100
  ) AS Percents;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8825d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested code but this should do it for you:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMERINFO
where member between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31') / 
(select COUNT(DISTINCT ORDERINFO.OrderID) from orderinfo, orderiteminfo 
where code = '810samp' 
AND ORDERINFO.OrderID = ORDERITEMINFO.OrderID
AND orderinfo.PrepareDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
* 100
```

An Alternate would be

```
DECLARE @int1 as int
DECLARE @int2 as int
SET @int1 = (SELECT count(*) FROM CUSTOMERINFO
    where member between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
SET @int2 = (select COUNT(DISTINCT ORDERINFO.OrderID) from orderinfo, orderiteminfo 
    where code = '810samp' 
    AND ORDERINFO.OrderID = ORDERITEMINFO.OrderID
    AND orderinfo.PrepareDate between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
SELECT @int1/@int2 X 100
```